# Compare values from a range of cells to another cell and display msgbox for certain criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a value in `B4` I need to pop a msgbox if the values in `C7:C10` are higher than the value in `B4`.  I also need a different msgbox to pop if the any of the cell values = 20.  I have it working in the first cell `C7` but I don't know how to get the range to work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    Dim One As Long
    Dim Two As Long

    One = Range("B4").Value
    Two = Range("C7").Value

    If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("B1:D10"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
        If (Two = 20) Then
            MsgBox "This requires a SOW!"
        ElseIf (One < Two) Then
            MsgBox "The Number Exceeds the Package!" & vbNewLine & "Change the package or decrease the number."
        End If
    End If

ExitSub:

End Sub
```

I don't know how to modify the code to look at the range and not just the one cell.

Comment: "if any of the cell values" - whenever you're facing a situation where you're looking at "a bunch of X" and need to do something with "each X", what you want is to introduce a loop. See what `For...Next`, `For Each...Next`, and `Do...Loop` can do for you.

Comment: Hi Edna, Right now there are no references to the full range you're talking about in your question. For `C7:C10`, are you trying to compare these all against `B4`? If so we can draft up a loop function that would work.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look very useful to me, so am guessing you want more to happen but this should start you off.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range

If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("B1:D10"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
    For Each r In Range("C7:C10")
        If r.Value > Range("B4").Value Then MsgBox r.Address & " is bigger than B4"
        If r.Value = 20 Then MsgBox r.Address & " is 20"
    Next r
End If

End Sub
```